# Pulling data out of Promises

Tags: javascript, async-await

How do I actually get data out of a Promise when using async/await?
I've written an async function to gather some data that will be used later in the script. There are two fetch calls, with the second call being dependent upon the first. I understand that an async function will always return a promise, but I can't figure out how to get the data out of it.

I've tried both:

```
const my_async_function = async() => {
    try {
        const foo = await fetch(`api/foo/uuid`).then(res => res.json());
        const bar = await fetch(`api/bar/${foo.uuid}`).then(res => res.json());
        return bar.find(el => el.name === 'hello');
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
const data = my_async_function().then(res => res.json());
```

and

```
let data;
const my_async_function = async() => {
    try {
        const foo = await fetch(`api/foo/uuid`).then(res => res.json());
        const bar = await fetch(`api/bar/${foo.uuid}`).then(res => res.json());
        return bar.find(el => el.name === 'hello');
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
my_async_function().then(res => {
    data = res.json();
});
```

but neither works. The first version throws an error and in the second version `data` remains undefind. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first version throws what error specifically?

Comment: If you put `console.log(data)` after `data = res.json();` you'll see the result.

Comment: In the first one, if you do `data.then(d => console.log(d))` it should work.

Comment: If you're trying to access `data` outside `.then()` it won't work, because that runs synchronously and doesn't wait for the async code to finish.